# How to connect IRQ output of XPS INTC to Microblaze Interrupt input

Tags: vhdl, interrupt, microblaze, xilinx-edk

I have written a custom PLB core for my design, and added interrupt functionality during custom core generation. Interrupt generation logic is designed in custom peripheral. For interrupt control, I added XPS interrupt controller (v2.01a) to the system and connected my custom core's interrupt ports to INTC via master bus. However, as I need to connect IRQ output of INTC to Interrupt input of Microblaze (v8.40), I cannot connect those two ports using Ports tab of System Assembly View, there is no connection option except external port and core's itself. I tried to do it manually on .MHS file, but still I cannot see IRQ and Interrupt ports connected in Graphical Design View. Besides, in Bus Interfaces tab of Assembly View, I can see INTERRUPT port of Microblaze but again, no change can be made.

[image: Bus interface tab, no way to connect any ports to Interrupt Input]

[image: Ports tab, no way to connect IRQ output to any other port]

Answer (score 0):

Use AXI_INTC insteed of XPS_INTC and it should work.

There you will find two bus :

- AXI BUS
- INTERRUPT BUS.

You will be able to connect the interrupt bus to your MicroBlaze component